# lazy loading asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit accordion

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the  asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit accordion (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Accordion.ashx) and each accordion pane contains quite a lof information.

All that info is generated in the page but it is not shown because the toolkit gives the non active panes a

```
 (style="display:none;)
```

But because the info is in the page, it becomes a very heavy page to load.

I am looking for a way to load the panes on-demand: so only if the user clicks the pane an ajax request is send and the pane is loaded and expanded.

Can this be done with this control or should i choose a different accordion? Any help or suggestions appreciated.

**update**
Currently the Accordion is created with two, nested, repeaters. The first repeater loops over the categories and creates a panel for each category. The second repeater repeates inside each panel takes the content for one category and creates the content of the panel.

Pleun

Comment: Have you checked out the JQuery Accordian?  This is probably better suited to what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the points to comment and ask you questions.  Sorry.  **:(**
My questions are in regard to how you plan to create and populate the Accordion.

Will you create panes by hand using markup in the IDE or will you bind the Accordion to a DataSource that will dynamically create the panes you need?

Will you have 3 separate DataSources or a different combination of the following:
    1.) DataSource to initialize the number of panels and populate only the panel's Header information.
    2.) DataSource to populate the Static Content of all panels on first load.
    3.) DataSource to populate the Lazy-Loaded Content of a single panel the user clicks to expand.

With your answers I hope to update this answer with a real one.  Thanks.

**Update:  This *is* achievable with the Ajax Control Toolkit's Accordion.**
I have some *very* basic code below as proof of concept.  It could be smoother, but I'll leave it up to you to add a "Loading" image using the UpdatingProgress control if you find it necessary.

**The Accordion in the Aspx markup:**
(Notice the UpdatePanels - you can replace them with callbacks if you want, I just wanted to keep the answer simple)

```
<asp:Accordion ID="acc_Accordion" runat="server" RequireOpenedPane="false" 
        SelectedIndex="-1" onitemcommand="acc_Accordion_ItemCommand" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_UpdateHeader" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <%--When using "Eval" inside strings for Asp.net controls,
                you MUST wrap them in apostrophes ('),
                otherwise with (") you will get parser errors!--%>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Header" runat="server"
                 Text='<%# Eval("HeaderText") %>'
                 CommandName="UpdatePane" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>'
                 Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="Black"
                 style="width:100%; height:100%; cursor:pointer;"/>
                 <%--Use Cursor:Pointer to keep a consistent
                     interface after disabling the button.--%>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_UpdateContent" runat="server"
                         UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ContentText")%>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Content" runat="server"
                     Text="<%# DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:Accordion>
```

**The Page_Load()** - Prep our "dummy" data:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemID");
        dt.Columns.Add("HeaderText");
        dt.Columns.Add("ContentText");

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 123456, "Header 1", "Content A." });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 654321, "Header 2", "Content B." });

        acc_Accordion.DataSource = new System.Data.DataTableReader(dt);
        acc_Accordion.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**The ItemCommand()** - This captures button-clicks inside the Accordion:

```
protected void acc_Accordion_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "UpdatePane")
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel acp
            = (e as AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionCommandEventArgs).Container;
        UpdatePanel upHeader
            = acc_Accordion.Panes[acp.DisplayIndex].HeaderContainer
             .Controls.OfType<Control>()
             .Single(c => c is UpdatePanel) as UpdatePanel;
        LinkButton btn
            = upHeader.ContentTemplateContainer
             .Controls.OfType<Control>()
             .Single(b => b is LinkButton) as LinkButton;
        UpdatePanel upContent
            = acc_Accordion.Panes[acp.DisplayIndex].ContentContainer
             .Controls.OfType<Control>()
             .Single(c => c is UpdatePanel) as UpdatePanel;
        Label lbl
            = upContent.ContentTemplateContainer
             .Controls.OfType<Control>()
             .Single(c => c is Label) as Label;
        lbl.Text = " ID: " + e.CommandArgument
                 + " and Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        //You can use the ID from e.CommandArgument to query the database
        // for data to update your Repeaters with.
        btn.Enabled = false;//Disabling the button for our Header
        // will prevent Asyncronous Postbacks to update the content again.
        //Only disable this if you don't need to update the content
        // when the user clicks to view the pane again.
        upContent.Update();//Set UpdateMode="Conditional".
    }
}
```

I know this looks like a lot, but it's only a few lines of code (before wrapping and commenting).

Comment: See my updated answer, i now have a combination of 1+2 but this can change

Comment: I also wanted to point out that you can easily find your controls by name using the following code: Label lbl = upContent.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("lbl_Content") as Label;  I prefer to avoid strings when I can but it may execute a few nanoseconds faster than my code above.

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for gave code , i used above code working fine but i have another simple concept expand multiple panes, when i click second time that time only Collapsed clicked pane(already it expand time only) , how to handle

Answer (score 2):

Tip 4 in [6 Tips for Working with the ASP.NET AJAX Accordion Control](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=215) explains how to determine when the selected index has changed. From the JavaScript event handler you can do whatever you want to update the content of the newly-selected accordion pane (call a web service, use an update panel, etc.)

Combining this with another article explaining [how to use an update panel to refesh content](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html) when a tab page is selected for a simple demo:

```
    <ajaxToolKit:Accordion ID="accSample" runat="server"
 RequireOpenedPane="false" SelectedIndex="-1">
 <Panes>
  <ajaxToolKit:AccordionPane runat="server">
   <Header>Sample</Header>
   <Content>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSample" runat="server" OnClick="OnShowSample" Style="display: none" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.Application.add_load(function (sender, args) {
   if (!args.get_isPartialLoad()) { 
    var accSample = $find('<%= accSample.ClientID %>_AccordionExtender');
    accSample.add_selectedIndexChanged(function (sender, eventArgs) {
     $get('<%= btnSample.ClientID %>').click();
    });
   }
  });
 </script>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSample" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:DataGrid ID="dgSample" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSample" />
  </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </Content>
  </ajaxToolKit:AccordionPane>
 </Panes>
</ajaxToolKit:Accordion>
```

then in code-behind

```
protected void OnShowSample(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 dgSample.DataSource = new string[] { "test" };
 dgSample.DataBind();
 dgSample.Visible = true; 
}
```

Comment: Did you test this code?  When controls are nested inside a bindable control, you cannot access them directly from the code-behind, like you did with dgSample, because there can be many instances.  You have to dig them out of a specific instance of the binded control.  See my answer, you may want to update yours to check the current selected index of your accSample to find and update the correct instance of your dgSample.  Use this to start and see what works: accSample.Panes[accSample.SelectedIndex]....

Comment: This is all you need if you're not going crazy nesting inside repeaters. Still useful, not quite what was asked, but since this is the first google result for lazy loading accordions (the original version of the question) I think it's fine.

Comment: You're right, I did jump the gun there.  If you hard-code each pane, this is all you need, but if you want to dynamically create your panes by binding to data, then this solution would need adjusting.  Based on the question's requirements, your answer is fine.  I like mine because it's more robust if you're into binding accordions to data to instantiate your panes dynamically.  I think I'll combine your javascript approach with what I have, that way I can get rid of the update panel in my header.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **ASPxNavBar** control (a part of the free [ASPxperience Suite](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/)) from **DevExpress**. If the **ASPxNavBar’s EnableCallBacks** property is set to **true**, contents of collapsed groups are not represented on the client side. When a group is expanded for the first time, its content is retrieved from the server and then cached on the client. The next time the group is expanded, its content is taken from the client and no callback to the server is performed.

Review the [ASPxNavBar - Callbacks (AJAX)](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/NavBar/EnableCallBacks.aspx) Online Demo for more information.

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest to you is add linkButtons to your headers and panels to your panes:

```
        <Panes>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="First" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="ASD2" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="true">
                         First
                    </asp:Panel>
                </Content>
            </asp:AccordionPane>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="Second" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="ASD" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
                         Second
                    </asp:Panel>
                </Content>
            </asp:AccordionPane>
        </Panes>
```

and in the `Accordion1_ItemCommand` set the `Visible` property of corresponding panel.

```
protected void Accordion1_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. How does a panel with Visible = false render in the browser? Is it not rendered. this would also cause postbacks or not?

Comment: Panel with Visible = false is not rendered on server. Yes, it will produce callbacks. You should add some logic for partial page redrawing.